# React-router: unable to pass context

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using child Context technique to pass context to the children of the application.

The Child context is passed successfully to the ***Header component***, but not on the ***Encounter Component***.
Any idea to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Application:

```
 export default class Application extends React.Component {
 constructor(props, context){
  super(props);
  this._onDataReceived=this._onDataReceived.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
 PersonalStore._onDataReceived(this._onDataReceived);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 PersonalStore._offDataReceived(this._onDataReceived);
}

getChildContext() {
 return { name:"Moussawi7" };
}
renderRouter(){
 ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
  <Route path="/" component={Encounter} />
  <Route path="inbox">
  <IndexRoute component={Inbox} onEnter={()=>this.refreshScroller()}/>
  <Route path=":userID" component={Conversation} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
  ),document.getElementById('content'));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <Header/>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    );
}
_onDataReceived() {
  this.renderRouter();
}
}
Application.childContextTypes={
 name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Header:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props,context) {
    super(props,context);
    console.log(context);// Object{name:"Moussawi7"}
  }
}
Header.contextTypes= {
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
```

Encounter:

```
export default class Encounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props,context) {
    super(props,context);
    console.log(context);//  Object {name:undefined}
  }
}
Encounter.contextTypes= {
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
```

Comment: Why not render the router directly in your render method instead of rendering separately in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @Morhaus, my code is much complex than this example, so i start routing once i received data. The below answer solved the issue. thank you.

Comment: @Morhaus,According to "componentDidMount" I already updated the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Morhause says this is likely to be your problem. The advised way to do it is that router is the base element, and Application wraps the other routes. Here I wrap Provider around the router so that everything has access to the context of the Provider:

```
// Provider.js Your app context provider

import React, { Component, PropTypes, Children } from 'react'

class Provider extends Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            name: 'Moussawi7'
        };
    }

    render() {
        let { children } = this.props;
        return Children.only(children);
    }
}

// Router.js Your Provider+Router is the first thing rendered on the root, not Application, which is the base route

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider>
        <Router>
            <Route path='/' component={Application}>
                <IndexRoute component={Encounter} />
                <Route path='users' component={Users} />
                <Route path="inbox">
                    <IndexRoute component={Inbox} onEnter={()=>this.refreshScroller()}/>
                    <Route path=":userID" component={Conversation} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);

// Your Application renders the child routes

class Application extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to='/users'>Users</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <div className='route-content'>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Note I used es7's `static` in those examples which would need babel stage 0 I believe, but you can put them outside the class.

Comment: You are right,react router should be the base element, but my code is much complex than the example i provided. I need to start rendering once i received data otherwise i have to provide conditions in each component. Thank you, Golden answer:)